# How can I undo Coding by Search in RQDA?

Tags: rstudio, rqda

I used codingBySearch to label instances (across all my files) and I have just noticed that I would like to undo two of my executions. How can I undo these runs?

I know that I can manually "unmark" the auto-coded phrases but there are way too many and, from looking at the codings, I am not 100% sure on which basis which coding was done. Thanks in advance!